# How do I make UpdateOrInsert in Kotlin collections

Tags: collections, kotlin

I have a list of items, and one of item copies is changed by user, how do I find it in my collection by Id and update, or if it's not found I'd like to add the item?  my best guess is, but it requires ugly *indexOf(v)*

```
fun updateOrInsert(note : UserNote) {
    val list = notes.value!!
    val v = list.firstOrNull{(Id) -> Id ==note.Id}
    if (v==null) {
        list.add(note)
    } else {
        val i = list.indexOf(v)
        list[i] = note
    }

    notes.value = list
}
```

Comment: You don't need that last line `notes.value = list`.

Comment: it's android LiveData magic, so under the hood it sends events

Comment: Ah, okay. Haven't done anything with LiveData, yet, but I get what you're saying. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [indexOfFirst](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index-of-first.html) to find the index of the first element with the given ID. If -1, add the item to the list, otherwise, change the value at the found index.

Comment: Don't know if the one line requirement can be satisfied, but at least using `indexOfFirst` could save you multiple iterations over the list: `fun updateOrInsert(note: UserNote) { val index = notes.value!!.indexOfFirst { it.Id == note.Id }; if (index == -1) { notes.value.add(note) } else { notes.value[index] = note } }`